# Wagtail - Change image tags/format in Rich Text Editor

Tags: django, wagtail, hallo-js

I'm using wagtail without its templates (I built an API using rest-framework).
I would like to change the format of the images in the rich text editor

For example this is my RichText field right now:

```
<p>test test test</p>
<p><br/></p><p><embed alt=\"IMG_1232.jpg\" embedtype=\"image\" format=\"test\" id=\"4\"/><br/></p>"
```

Instead I would like it to include only the direct link to the image, and even better to the image with the filter I defined (with register_image_format).
e.g.:

```
<p>test test test</p>
<p><br/></p><p><embed href="/media/IMG_1232.width-400"/><br/></p>"
```

Is it possible?
I looked into hallo.js but not sure what to do with it...

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Add a method to your model which returns the result of calling the `richtext` filter on your rich text field. You can then use this method in place of the field itself within the `api_fields` definition:

```
from wagtail.core.templatetags import wagtailcore_tags

def MyPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField()

    def rendered_body(self):
        return wagtailcore_tags.richtext(self.body)

    api_fields = [
        APIField('rendered_body'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the full URL for images, embed and documents, you have to run the content of the richtext block through the richtext `filter` template tag.

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.templatetags import wagtailcore_tags

rich_text = wagtailcore_tags.richtext(rich_text_source)
```

`rich_text` should have embed and images with full URL.

Using with DRF it would look something like this, if your doing it in your serializer

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers
from wagtail.wagtailcore.templatetags import wagtailcore_tags

class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    rich_text = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_rich_text(self, obj):
        return wagtailcore_tags.richtext(obj.rich_text.source)
```

Comment: I'm not using the templates (I'm working with DRF). I'm now using the stream fields. Do you know if it is possible? Thanks

Comment: that's the way I have mentioned above just pass the html source to the `wagtailcore_tags.richtext` function. It will expand the URL's for you

Comment: The images aren't in RichText but in ImageChooserBlock. I'm not sure it's possible, and I have to hit the DB twice for each image - one to get the image object from its ID and one to get the image_rendition. Thanks